# get country and city information from wikimapia Api

Tags: geolocation, reverse-geocoding, wikimapia

I need to know in which country (and hopefully some more info, like city or area or state and it would be great if I could get whether this is on land or sea) a coordinates set lies in.
I have tried the wikimapia api but it is extremely difficult to get around to it.
for example I have this call
http://api.wikimapia.org/?function=box&key=example&bbox=23.72251,37.96918,23.73094,37.9731&format=json
which brings some information about an area in Athens, Greece.
The problem is that not only this api call is depreciated, but when i try to get the country by adding &category=2977
http://api.wikimapia.org/?function=box&key=example&bbox=23.72251,37.96918,23.73094,37.9731&format=json&category=1176
this doesnt work(the category id i got it from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/effrenus/6989940))

I would guess that this might have something to do with the method being depreciated, but when I change to the new method [place.getbyarea](http://wikimapia.org/api/?action=how_to#placegetbyarea) it is not working at all.
http://api.wikimapia.org/?function=place.getbyarea&key=example&bbox=23.72251,37.96918,23.73094,37.9731&format=json

Any ideas? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want specifically the API of Wikimapia to get your information? To recover the city and country from GPS coordinates, some others API’s are much more appropriate I think, here some examples:

- [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) ([used here in a webpage](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse))
- [Here Maps](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/reverse-geocode)
- [Bing Maps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx)
- [Apple Maps (Mapkit.js)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs/mapkit/geocoder)
- [Algolia Places](https://community.algolia.com/places/rest.html)
- [OpenStreetMap Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim)